# How to use the param of 'weights' of tensorflow function tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, weighted-average, seq2seq

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.2,0.1,0.4,0.3],[0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1],[0.3,0.2,0.1,0.4],[0.1,0.4,0.3,0.2]], dtype=tf.float32)
B = tf.constant([1, 2, 1, 3, 3], dtype=tf.int32)

w_1 = tf.constant(value=[1,1,1,1,1], dtype=tf.float32)
w_2 = tf.constant(value=[1,2,3,4,5], dtype=tf.float32)

D   = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([A], [B], [w_1])
D_1 = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([A], [B], [w_1], average_across_timesteps=False)
D_2 = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([A], [B], [w_2])
D_3 = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([A], [B], [w_2], average_across_timesteps=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(D))
  print(sess.run(D_1))
  print(sess.run(D_2))
  print(sess.run(D_3))
```

And the result is:

```
[1.4425355 1.2425355 1.3425356 1.2425356 1.4425356]

[1.4425355 1.2425355 1.3425356 1.2425356 1.4425356]

[1.4425355 1.2425355 1.3425356 1.2425356 1.4425356]

[1.4425355 2.485071  4.027607  4.9701424 7.212678 ]
```

I don't understand why the result is the same no matter if the param `average_across_timesteps` is set as 'True' or 'False'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source code that performs the averaging:

```
if average_across_timesteps:
  total_size = math_ops.add_n(weights)
  total_size += 1e-12  # Just to avoid division by 0 for all-0 weights.
  log_perps /= total_size
```

In your case, the `weights` is a list of *one* tensor, either `w_1` or `w_2`, i.e., you have one time step. In both cases, `tf.add_n(weights)` doesn't change it, because it's a sum of one element (not the sum of elements in `w_1` or `w_2`).

This explains the result: `D` and `D_1` are evaluated to the same arrays, because `D_1 = D * w_1` (element-wise). `D_2` and `D_3` are different because `w_2` contains not only ones.

Comment: Thank you very much! math_ops.add_n([1,2,3,4,5])=[1,2,3,4,5]My confusion is lifted，thanks again!